# Get a <tr> ID which is generated dinamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the  id from the checkbox below

```
<% @task.each do |task| %>

        <tr id="tr_<%= task.id%>">
          <td><%= check_box_tag "done[#{task.id}]",task.id, task.done, data:{
              remote: true,
              url: url_for(action: :toggle, id: task.id, checked: task.done),
              method: "POST"
          } %> </td>
          <td><%= task.title %></td>
          <td><%= task.detail %></td>
          <td><%= task.task_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
          <td><%= button_to('Show', task_path(task) , :class => 'btn btn-default', :method => :get)  %></td>
          <td><%= button_to('Edit', edit_task_path(task), :class => 'btn btn-primary',:method => :get)  %></td>
          <td><%= button_to('Remove', task_path(task), :class => 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

My JS is running as expected but i didn't figure out how to do it dinamically.

```
$("#tr_37").change(function(){
         $(this).hide();
     });
```

Comment: change `$("#tr_37").change(function(){` to `$(document).on("change","#tr_37",function(){` see `.on()`

Comment: didn't work and not doing it dinamically =/

Comment: `didn't figure out how to do it dynamically.` ?can you elaborate on this what is dynamically aded

Comment: <tr id="tr_<%= task.id%>"> I'm setting the tr id dinamically. How can i get it on the jquery to hide the row?

Comment: you want to get the id of tr which is dynamically added when you check a checkbox?just do `$(this).closest('tr').hide()`

Comment: How can you set a change event to your TR tag??? And you say it's working as expected.. I don't think so..  What is #tr_37??

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').hide()` make sure you capture the checked event of the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want hide `tr` when checkbox changed?

I think you need catch event of checkbox when changed

```
$("tr input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

Comment: tr_37 is an example of generated id. It can be tr_1, tr_2, tr_3